# C++ Multipath Inheritance : Why the access using Base class scope is non-ambiguous?

Tags: c++, inheritance, virtual-inheritance, diamond-problem

I am studying C++ and while studying virtual inheritance, I came across following doubt:

```
class A {
public:
    int x;
    A() { x = 677; }
    A(int a) { 
        cout << "A con , x= " << a << endl;
        x = a;
    }
};
class B : public A {
public:
    B(int a) : A(a) { }
};
class C :public A {
public:
    C(int a) : A(a) { }
};
class D : public B, public C {
public:
    D(int a,int b) : B(a),C(b) { }
};
int main()
{
    D d(5,6);
    cout << d.A::x;  //prints 5 
 }
```

In line `cout << d.A::x;` It prints 5. Shouldn't this call be ambiguous and if not why it prints 5?

Comment: How many different compilers did you try? Check if GCC, Clang and MSVC all agree or not. If not, you're probably flirting with undefined behaviour.

Comment: Did you enable compiler warnings?

Comment: Latest GCC and Clang gives compile errors on Godbolt default settings. MSVC is happy to compile, but I don't read MASM well enough to be able to tell you what it would output and Godbolt doesn't have the option to execute code compiled with MSVC at the moment.

Comment: @LouisCloete different compilers not agreeing is a rather weak indicator for UB. Very often different compilers don't disagree even though there is UB. And sometimes they disagree without any UB in sight

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`d.A::x;` is indeed ambiguous. GCC and Clang report it as error, only MSCV fails to do so: https://godbolt.org/z/1zhjdE6a8.

There is a note in [[class.mi]](https://eel.is/c++draft/class.derived#class.mi) with an example of multiple inheritance stating that:

> In such lattices, explicit qualification can be used to specify which subobject is meant.
> The body of function C​::​f can refer to the member next of each L subobject:
>
> ```
> void C::f() { A::next = B::next; }      // well-formed
> ```
>
> Without the `A​::`​ or `B​::`​ qualifiers, the definition of `C​::​f` above would be ill-formed because of ambiguity ([class.member.lookup]).
> — end note]

It is just a note, because it follows from `[class.member.lookup]` (which is a little more contrived to read and understand) that without the qualifier the member access is ambiguous. "ill-formed" implies that a conforming compiler must issue either an error or warning.

Answer (score 1):

This is ambiguous according to both GCC and Clang, but MSVC compiles it ([Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/#z:OYLghAFBqd5QCxAYwPYBMCmBRdBLAF1QCcAaPECAMzwBtMA7AQwFtMQByARg9KtQYEAysib0QXACx8BBAKoBnTAAUAHpwAMvAFYTStJg1DIApACYAQuYukl9ZATwDKjdAGFUtAK4sGIAMykrgAyeAyYAHI%2BAEaYxBKBAA6oCoRODB7evgGkyamOAqHhUSyx8VyBdpgO6UIETMQEmT5%2BlZj2BQx1DQRFkTFxCbb1jc3ZlSO9Yf2lgxUAlLaoXsTI7Bzm/mHI3lgA1Cb%2Bbk4KBMSYrIfYJhoAgje3XqlGe8xsColMa3un6IdWdweOyYCgUe1uBwA7ADbokvNFaHhkCAHns0XswgQ9qp/qj0bcIPMoRZsQd/AARPYANkhkP%2BUPJeLRBMxeyYRJM0IOd3RvL2aC8WMObmFBzMZghaAYe1I2MOlPMZjJIqObOVotctFxPL5aNUZMpTG1EPRnMZgMhjP8MOBoL2JJAezhCKR4OJD2diORTPtEFZ7L2joJAc5JLND3D1qBBjtbkDntdENDHvhXpROrRbj9gjZRKDEBDXPDFqtNpjYMpjoTyHtsurezjybu1fTJrR5OzWKY5Bz0TzvvZpCzfeJDIjluNrJYTDChPHMN5lPQEAArKQqfNjbyBUKjqL0AA6W4gEA461ogD0F8SxExYJX3KTlo4i1onBXvD8HC0pFQnBFljWD8yyrJgYr%2BDwpAEJoL6LAA1iAZiSAeACcaHoRhGFUvonCSJ%2BMG/pwvAKCAGhQTBixwLASBoCwiR0HE5CULR9H0PEwBcFwZh8HQBBxCREDRAR0RhA0ACenCQbRbCCAA8gwtASd%2BvBYNORjiMppD4OcNQAG6YCRmmYKo1SCuskGYu0BGItExDiR4WAEWceAsJJL58AYwAKAAangmAAO6yYkjBuTIggiGI7BSGF8hKGoBG6Fw%2BiGMY1jWPoeDRCRkCLKgiSdIZxHtNUnQuAw7ieC0IAoWRITTCUZQgNIeRpAIYx%2BDVuQpK1DB9A1gzSFUNQCN0oyVdknVDZ0o1TMUAzxINkztdVZGnD0fXzU1iwKCBax6GcmDme5b4cB%2BpBfj%2Bf4cKoAAcVIALRUpIezAMgNacQeSoQABViWLKuCECQ4FJQ2qB0QxxDA/MvDQcp8zwYhyGYcj6HYSdeHnQRV3EaR5Fw6QVGICgYOsYxFAQCxEMgLpyCJIkAD6ulcCh9NmCz3lCFwVL05x9OqE9PG0HxxACUJmkicwxBKVJYMyQQ8mKQRqkpRpP7aSVeD6YZP7GaZfGhZZJ0/jZdlSw56w/s5rncO5VCeT5fmBcFX6Qfw4WiOI0Vu7FKjqJpujcQYRgoGlf02dlhK/vl6SFbYxXDX4ECuMtSV1XNszlF1%2BTpCnWc9RtGd6FNtRLeNfhJcXI2TAXjUV6XWTl8M631ZtXDbbtUVQecR2vu%2B%2BGaVd/PPSwCg03sTMoZ9KF7BzXMHpxezfaHNh7ADRCQ5sIMeODbHgWY0N41o8OkAhSGoSjyNo7h/eXURti47DR8EzAROU2xTEUyTVPAkYFQaGRNAhb8UoGLH8EtxKhWkoweWCklJq0wGpYAqsVJ4B0o4LWBFdbIDMgbQQVlNIm3shgC2MNbzWx4IsO2TAvK%2BQCkFEKNsYoRU9tIb2ihfYJRyEHVKgEw6ZQjrlaOAhY6V0TsnMueg04zFrnnToucWqdBrnMOOHQS49FzqImaSjM5rTGg3Iu1cW6FzbksFYe0koHR7jhU6N9eCDzuo9Z6P9gB7AqAeDQ7jF4/XSqvfA69gaym3qTDeZh/D%2BAPo/WCJ9EJrnRrYwiHAcZkUicfE6Zh4nY0PlE/SIt0hNSAA%3D%3D))

You can solve it by using virtual inheritance for `B` and `C` if it makes sense to only have one instance of A in D or you can specify via which parent the call must access `A::x` if you need two distinct instances of A in D.

```cpp
std::cout << d.B::x; // go through B to its A
std::cout << d.C::x; // go through C to its A
```

The above compiles on all 3 compilers without error, because it is unambiguous. It specifies through which intermediate class to access `A::x`.

Comment: Be careful about recommending virtual inheritance. It is not a **coding** solution to ambiguities; it's a **design** decision. Yes, it could remove the ambiguity, but if there are supposed to be two `x` members, changing to virtual inheritance breaks the design.

Comment: @PeteBecker I added a part about the tradeoffs with virtual inheritance and gave an alternative if you need two unique instances. Do you agree with it?